# Drupal 7 Media Library in CKEditor works on only one user

Tags: drupal-7, wysiwyg, media-library

This baffling issue seems to be happening for everyone except the first account.

Using CKEditor and the Medial Library plugin, Media WYSIWYG plugin, Media WYSIWYG view mode (if that's relevant)

So basically the idea is that we have 3 admin accounts. Each having only the role of administrator:
[image]

The top account there is the only one who gets a "upload/browse server" button when clicking the image icon in the WYSIWYG.

[image]

Meanwhile, all other accounts get this:

[image]

Considering that (so much as I know) Drupal has a role based permission system and not a per-user based system, what would be the cause for this "upload/browse server" utility only being available to one single account?

I've checked all the WYSIWYG display settings, permissions, clearing cache, etc. All looks ok and I don't really see any account specific settings that could be related to this.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This issue screams Permissions Problem to me!

Comment: @Collins - sure does. Ever heard of Drupal having permissions based on user and not role? cause if that exists I don't know where. All accounts are set to administrator. They all share the same role. What then is the system using to determine these accounts dont get the same UI for media library? I don't see it

Comment: Yeah there are some differences for user 1, for example, no matter what you set, no other user can cancel user 1. I'm not sure of the case for media as I don't use it I'm afraid.